# If the Latin word for goose, "anser", really comes from Proto-Indo-European *gjhh2ens, where did the *gjh disappear? Why didn't it change to 'h'?

Tags: etymology

If the Latin word for goose, "anser", really comes from Proto-Indo-European *g<sup>jh</sup>h<sub>2</sub>ens, where did the *g<sup>jh</sup> disappear? Why didn't it change to 'h', as in "homo" (human) from *g<sup>jh</sup>mo?

Comment: Initial *h-* is expected but initial *h-* is unstable in Latin at the best of times and happens to have disappeared. Please don't write palatovelars like that.

Comment: @Cairnarvon Then how should I write palatovelars?

Comment: The way literally everyone else does and the way you've certainly seen them written, as \*ǵ or \*g̑. \*gʲ gives too much weight to their pronunciation as palatalised velars, which is not at all a given (they're *called* palatovelars effectively *faute de mieux*).

Comment: @FlatAssembler There are a frustrating number of different conventions for writing PIE, but most of them agree on writing the "palatovelars" with the letters K and G, plus some sort of accent mark (most commonly the acute). An alternative I've warmed to is using C and J instead, which makes typing far easier, but I only use it in my own notes and casual conversations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We would expect an *h*, but as Cairnavon put it in the comments, "*h-* is unstable in Latin at the best of times". It's very common for *h* to disappear, as in *have* > *ave* "hello" and *harena* > *arena* "sand", or to get added in where it's not expected, as in *alucinor* > *halucinor* "dream".

During the Classical era, pronouncing *h* correctly was a mark of refinement; most people didn't, and Catullus mocks people who try to imitate educated pronunciation and get it wrong. The common pronunciation won out over time, as it tends to do, and *h* disappeared entirely in Romance.

Or, in the laconic words of De Vaan:
[image: initial *h- has been dropped]

Comment: Is it exceptional that of these words *anser* alone doesn't have a form with the initial h-? You see *harena* plenty early, but never, as far as I can tell, *hanser*.

Comment: @cmw Since this process was happening so early on, I'm guessing there are a bunch of other vowel-initial words that originally had *h but lost it before Classical times (to the point that the educated Romans didn't know they were supposed to insert an /h/ there).

Comment: It is probably relevant that _anser_ belongs to the rural vocabluary. Snobbish urbanites willing not to drop their h’s were less likely to use it

Comment: @Dario Is that true, though? I don't think *hanser* is ever attested, so how do we know for sure? (Not disputing the etymology, just find it strange it sticks out. More parallels would be helpful.)